# DbContext returning some null values

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using `return _dbContext.Groups;` in my repository, it returns all my group objects but **one** object return null value field in TeamLeader.

Here are my class in Group

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public string GroupCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    [ForeignKey("Application")]
    public string? ApplicationCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Application? Application { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("TeamLeader")]
    public string TeamLeaderCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual User? TeamLeader { get; set; }


    public bool IsForChangeManagers { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<User>? Members { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using lazy loading

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>(g =>
            {
                g.HasOne(g => g.TeamLeader).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Group>(g => g.TeamLeaderCode);
                g.HasMany(g => g.Members).WithMany(u => u.Groups);
            });
        }
```

I also tried this, but it also return null in that field

```
 List<Group> groupList = new();
        var allGroup = _dbContext.Groups;

        foreach (var group in allGroup)
        {
            if (group.TeamLeader == null)
            {
                group.TeamLeader = _userRepository.GetUserByCode(group.TeamLeaderCode);
                groupList.Add(group);
            } else
            {
                groupList.Add(group);
            }
        }
        return groupList;
```

Here the result:
[image]

Comment: Please review and [edit] the tags on your question. This code is definitely not C.

Comment: Matching strings is always tricky. Maybe there are case differences, or lading/trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, I just need to explicitly call the team leader property

```
       List<Group> groupList = _dbContext.Groups.ToList();
        var countList = _dbContext.Groups.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < countList; i++)
        {
            groupList[i].TeamLeader = _userRepository.GetUserByCode(groupList[i].TeamLeaderCode);

        }
       
        return groupList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way would be to explicitly **Include** the property you want populated.

```
return _dbContext.Groups.Include(g => g.TeamLeader).ToList()
```